# Store a Task of IList when only passed an IList

Tags: c#-4.0, task-parallel-library

I have the following property:

```
public Func<EntityKey, string, Task<IList<MyProperty>>> RequestHandler { get; private set; }
```

I also have a constructor on my class that looks like this:

```
public RequestHandlerTasks(Func<EntityKey, string, IList<MyProperty>> handler)
```

How can I manipulate the “handler” passed into the constructor so I can store it in the “RequestHandler” property ?

In case you haven’t spotted it, the constructor uses “IList” and the property wants a Task of IList.

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to *do* with these handlers. What is that property meant to achieve? Please give us more context.

Comment: This is a helper class that has an overloaded constructor. It can take either of the following: (Func<EntityKey, string, IList<MyProperty>> handler) or (Func<EntityKey, string, Task<IList<MyProperty>>> handler). An instance of this class is held in a dictionary. I should then be able to access this classes property to get a type of: Func<EntityKey, string, Task<IList<MyProperty>>>

Comment: That's described what members are available, but not what they're meant to *mean*.

Answer (score 2):

It's still not clear what the semantics are meant to be, but it *could* be as simple as:

```
public RequestHandlerTasks(Func<EntityKey, string, IList<MyProperty>> handler)
{
    // Whenever the RequestHandler delegate is called, it will start a new task.
    RequestHandler = (arg1, arg2) =>
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() => handler(arg1, arg2));
}
```

That will *compile* - whether it does what you *want* or not is a different matter...